# Preventing Race Condition on executing a Java Timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, race-condition, critical-section

I have a method `foo()` which is called several times through multiple threads. Inside the method is Critical Section.

```
private Object syncObject = new Object();
private Timer batchingTimer;
private TimerTask batchingAction;



public void foo() {
    synchronized(syncObject) {
        batchingTimer = new Timer();
        batchingAction = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                b();
            }
        };
        batchingTimer.schedule(batchingAction, 1000);
        a();
        b();
    }
}
```

Method `b()` runs inside `foo()` method and also inside the timer. This method sometimes faces with Race Condition (Java Timer Class for running `Action Method` creates a new thread).
How can I prevent Race Condition in this situation?

Comment: Follow the Java tutorial on synchronization https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Synchronize `b()` on something.